# Get child elements within casper.each

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Using CasperJS 1.1 with the following codes, I'm able to fetch useful DOM html from web page.

```
casper.each(c.getElementsInfo(xpath), function(casper, element, j) {
    var html = element["html"].trim();
    if(html.indexOf('Phone') > -1) {
        // what should I put here?
    }
});
```

However, I want to access & obtain the child elements of the element. How can I achieve this? Element's HTML source (a.k.a the value of `html`) is as follow:

**Loop 1**

```
<div class="fields">
                Phone
            </div>
            <div class="values">
                <a href="tel: 12345678">12345678</a> (Mr. Lee)              </div>
```

**Loop 2**

```
<div class="fields">
                Emergency Phone
            </div>
            <div class="values">
                <a href="tel: 23456789 (Emergency)">23456789 (Emergency)</a>
            </div>
```

**Loop 3**

```
<div class="fields">
                Opening Hours
            </div>
            <div class="values">
                9:00am-6:30pm(Weekday) /
                Close on Sundays and Public Holidays（Can be booked）(Holiday)
            </div>
```

**Loop 4**

```
<div class="fields">
                Last Update
            </div>
            <div class="values">
                 11/06/14               </div>
```

The above HTML is badly formatted, and contains a lot of whitespaces.

The data I wanted to fetch is:

- Phone: 12345678
- Emergency Phone: 23456789 (Emergency)
- Opening Hours: 9:00am-6:30pm(Weekday) / Close on Sundays and Public  Holidays（Can be booked）(Holiday)
- Last Update: 11/06/14

Tried RegEx, but the RegEx is too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend doing this with regular expressions. It can be easily done with some selectors, but it has to be done in the page context (inside of the `evaluate()` callback), because DOM nodes cannot be passed to the outside.

CasperJS provides a helper function for matching DOM nodes by XPath with [`__utils__.getElementsByXPath()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#getelementsbyxpath) through the ClientUtils module that is always automatically inserted. The result of that function is an array, so the normal `forEach()` pattern applies. DOM nodes can be used as context nodes for selecting child elements with `el.querySelector(".class")`.

```
var info = casper.evaluate(function(xpath){
    var obj = {};
    __utils__.getElementsByXPath(xpath).forEach(function(el){
        obj[el.querySelector(".fields").textContent.trim()] = 
            el.querySelector(".values").textContent.trim();
    });
    return obj;
}, yourXPathString);
```

If you want to select elements based on a CSS selector use the following:

```
var info = casper.evaluate(function(cssSelector){
    var obj = {};
    __utils__.findAll(cssSelector).forEach(function(el){
        obj[el.querySelector(".fields").textContent.trim()] = 
            el.querySelector(".values").textContent.trim();
    });
    return obj;
}, yourCssSelector);
```

Comment: with the same Xpath & above codes, `info` returns `null` . Please advise.

Comment: This means that there was an error in that function. Can you register to the "page.error" event ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf))?

Comment: Note, that `yourXPathString` is expected to be a string and not the output of the `selectXPath` helper.

Comment: Registered `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` and `onConsoleMessage` as specified in your example link, no extra line has been displayed in console. Here is the [js file](http://pastebin.com/rnyz8cNu)

Comment: the `yourXPathString` is set to `var xpath = 'div[class="shop_details"] div[class="line"]';`

Comment: That's not an XPath expression. It's a CSS selector. I've updated my answer.